# why is the following code returning a xml output in webbroswer?

Tags: node.js, koa

```
const Koa = require('koa');
const app = new Koa();

const main = ctx => {
  if (ctx.request.accepts('xml')) {
    ctx.response.type = 'xml';
    ctx.response.body = '<data>Hello World</data>';
  } else if (ctx.request.accepts('json')) {
    ctx.response.type = 'json';
    ctx.response.body = { data: 'Hello World' };
  } else if (ctx.request.accepts('html')) {
    ctx.response.type = 'html';
    ctx.response.body = '<p>Hello World</p>';
  } else {
    ctx.response.type = 'text';
    ctx.response.body = 'Hello World';
  }
};

app.use(main);
app.listen(3000);
```

I'm playing this koa webframework for nodejs http://www.ruanyifeng.com/blog/2017/08/koa.html. Yet, I'm confused. I do not understand logically why is the above code, after running, would return a xml output. Could anyone shad some lights?

Comment: Open browser's dev tools, see the *Network* tab, select *All* in the filter row. Then hit F5, and check the very first request on the list. Click on it and see Request headers. There will be an `accept` header, which will tell you what response types your request accepts :)

Comment: ctx.response.type = 'xml'; // Is explicitly saying that the output is a xml.

Comment: @NickLeBlanc, but ctx.response.type = 'xml'; is inside of the if block, right? I mean, I'm confused about this part.

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek, is there anyway to set it up through the coding, not through the browser's part?

Comment: @stonestone I've never used the Koa framework, but I assume that `ctx.requets` is a normal `IncomingMessage` object, so try to just `console.log(ctx.request.headers)` and there should be an `accept` header which will contain all headers your requets accepts